# How to get all sub-tree branch combinations of a tree

Tags: python, tree, combinations, networkx, permutation

I have the following tree with branches from br_a to br_i and a root point.
[image: Full tree]

I would like to generate all possible subtree permutations of the this tree by permuting the branches only (not individual vertices) in Python. For example,

[image: Permutations]
[image: Permutations]

All permutations of branches must be connected to the root point and I don't want duplicates. How can I do this, I currently have this tree as [BigTree](https://github.com/kayjan/bigtree) object or a [NetworkX](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) graph. Do these libraries have any functions to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is one possible option:

```
all_paths = [
    p for desc in nx.descendants(G, "r0")
    for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, "r0", desc)
]

perms = set()
for path in all_paths:
    sg_nodes = set()
    for node in path:
        sg_nodes.add(node)
        for data in d.values():
            if node in data["nodes"]:
                sg_nodes.update(data["nodes"])
    perms.add(frozenset(G.subgraph(sg_nodes).nodes))
```

Output :

```
for idx, sg_nodes in enumerate(perms, 1):
    sg = G.subgraph(sg_nodes)
    print(f"Perm{idx}: {list(nx.topological_sort(sg))}")

Perm1: ['r0', 'a0', 'a1', 'd0', 'd1']
Perm2: ['r0', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'f0']
Perm3: ['r0', 'c0', 'i0', 'i1', 'i2']
Perm4: ['r0', 'c0']
Perm5: ['r0', 'c0', 'h0', 'h1', 'h2']
Perm6: ['r0', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2']
Perm7: ['r0', 'a0', 'a1']
Perm8: ['r0', 'a0', 'a1', 'e0', 'e1']
Perm9: ['r0', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'g0']
```

Graph used :

[image]

```
import networkx as nx

d = {
    "root point": {"nodes": ["r0"], "color": "lightpink"},
    "br_a": {"nodes": ["a0", "a1"], "color": "mediumpurple"},
    "br_b": {"nodes": ["b0", "b1", "b2"], "color": "magenta"},
    "br_c": {"nodes": ["c0"], "color": "cyan"},
    "br_d": {"nodes": ["d0", "d1"], "color": "lime"},
    "br_e": {"nodes": ["e0", "e1"], "color": "yellow"},
    "br_f": {"nodes": ["f0"], "color": "crimson"},
    "br_g": {"nodes": ["g0"], "color": "darkgreen"},
    "br_h": {"nodes": ["h0", "h1", "h2"], "color": "blue"},
    "br_i": {"nodes": ["i0", "i1", "i2"], "color": "brown"}
}

connections = [
    ("r0", "a0"),
    ("a0", "a1"),
    ("a1", "d0"),
    ("a1", "e0"),
    ("d0", "d1"),
    ("e0", "e1"),
    ("r0", "b0"),
    ("b0", "b1"),
    ("b1", "b2"),
    ("b2", "f0"),
    ("b2", "g0"),
    ("r0", "c0"),
    ("c0", "h0"),
    ("h0", "h1"),
    ("h1", "h2"),
    ("c0", "i0"),
    ("i0", "i1"),
    ("i1", "i2")
]

G = nx.DiGraph()

for br, data in d.items():
    G.add_nodes_from(data["nodes"], branch=br)

G.add_edges_from(connections)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the good start. The problem here is that we only get simple paths, so we don't get permutations like perm 4 in the original question. However, that can be solved by taking combinations of the simple path. I'll post a modified version of your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Timeless's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77693344/13970373), but adding all permutations including the simple paths.

```py
d = {
    "root point": {"nodes": ["r0"], "color": "lightpink"},
    "br_a": {"nodes": ["a0", "a1"], "color": "mediumpurple"},
    "br_b": {"nodes": ["b0", "b1", "b2"], "color": "magenta"},
    "br_c": {"nodes": ["c0"], "color": "cyan"},
    "br_d": {"nodes": ["d0", "d1"], "color": "lime"},
    "br_e": {"nodes": ["e0", "e1"], "color": "yellow"},
    "br_f": {"nodes": ["f0"], "color": "crimson"},
    "br_g": {"nodes": ["g0"], "color": "darkgreen"},
    "br_h": {"nodes": ["h0", "h1", "h2"], "color": "blue"},
    "br_i": {"nodes": ["i0", "i1", "i2"], "color": "brown"}}

connections = [
    ("r0", "a0"),
    ("a0", "a1"),
    ("a1", "d0"),
    ("a1", "e0"),
    ("d0", "d1"),
    ("e0", "e1"),
    ("r0", "b0"),
    ("b0", "b1"),
    ("b1", "b2"),
    ("b2", "f0"),
    ("b2", "g0"),
    ("r0", "c0"),
    ("c0", "h0"),
    ("h0", "h1"),
    ("h1", "h2"),
    ("c0", "i0"),
    ("i0", "i1"),
    ("i1", "i2")]

G = nx.DiGraph()

for br, data in d.items():
    G.add_nodes_from(data["nodes"], branch=br, color=data['color'])

G.add_edges_from(connections)

descendants = nx.descendants(G, "r0")
filtered_descendants = [node for node in descendants
                        if len(list(G.successors(node))) == 0 or len(list(G.successors(node))) > 1]

# get paths
all_paths = [
    p for desc in filtered_descendants
    for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, "r0", desc)
]

perms = set()
for path in all_paths:
    sg_nodes = set(path)
    perms.add(frozenset(G.subgraph(sg_nodes).nodes))

# Get all combinations of different lengths (1 to len(perms))
all_combinations = []
for r in range(1, len(perms) + 1):
    combinations_r = itertools.combinations(perms, r)
    all_combinations.extend(combinations_r)

# Merge each tuple of frozensets into a single frozenset
merged_combinations = [frozenset().union(*comb) for comb in all_combinations]
merged_combinations = set(merged_combinations)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using `bigtree`! Will be adding on to Roman's answer above, with the section on recovering the tree (his answer ends with getting a set of frozensets of strings but not the tree itself).

```
# Set up the tree
from bigtree import list_to_tree

tree = list_to_tree([
    "r0/a0/a1/d0/d1",
    "r0/a0/a1/e0/e1",
    "r0/b0/b1/b2/f0",
    "r0/b0/b1/b2/g0",
    "r0/c0/h0/h1/h2",
    "r0/c0/i0/i1/i2",
])

# Answer
from bigtree import findall
import itertools

# Get the end of each branch (should have 9 branches)
branches = findall(tree, lambda node: not node.is_root and len(node.children) != 1)
branches_path = [node.node_path for node in branches]

# Get all combinations of different lengths (should be 2**9 - 1 permutations)
all_combinations = []
for r in range(1, len(branches_path) + 1):
    combinations_r = itertools.combinations(branches_path, r)
    all_combinations.extend(combinations_r)

# Merge each tuple of frozensets into a single frozenset (removes duplicate)
merged_combinations = [frozenset().union(*comb) for comb in all_combinations]
merged_combinations = list(set(merged_combinations))

# Recover the tree(s)
tree_list = []
for comb in merged_combinations:
    tree = list_to_tree([node.path_name for node in comb])
    tree_list.append(tree)
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `bigtree` :)